# FFT convolution not being faster than the cannonical convolution computation

Tags: python, numba

A couple of months ago I found out that convolutions are computed in the fastest possible way using the FFT algorithm (even more with the FFTW library)

Using the following code I have controversial results.

Imports

```
from scipy import fftpack
from numba import jit
```

Convolution with FFT:

```
def conv_fft(X, R):
    n = len(X)   
    a = fftpack.fft(X)
    b = fftpack.fft(R)
    c = a * b
    e = fftpack.ifft(c)
    result = e[n]
    return result
```

Convolution using the formula:

```
@jit(cache=True)
def conv(X, R):
    n = len(X)      
    result = complex_type(0)
    for i in range(n+1):
        result += X[n-i] * R[i]
    return result
```

This are critical functions in a much complex process, the difference arises only by using one version or the other.

```
       no FFT     with FFT   increment
Test1  0.028761   0.034139   0.0053780
Test2  0.098565   0.103180   0.0046150
```

** the test2 computes more convolutions per test.*

The test show that the code with FFT is slower and I cannot see why since the fftpack apparently call the FFTW library which is *"the fastest in the west"*...

Any guidance is appreciated.

A conclusion for my is that the numba JIT compilation is unbelievably fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only returning a single value (the n:th one) of the convolution, not the full array. With FFT you always calculate all values, whereas in your conv function you only calculate the one you're after. Complexity-wise, the FFT is O(N*log(N)), and your implementation of conv is O(N). If you would implement a naive conv function that would return the full convolution, it would be O(N^2). 
So, if you want the full convoluted array your best bet is the FFT way of doing it. If you only want the n:th value, your method is complexity wise the best.

Comment: Is there a way to use the FFT algorithm to take the value that I need? Would it produce any gain?

Comment: If you only need the n:th value, there is no point really. You can do it the way you have done it, but with the FFT algorithm you have to compute all values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get away with creating fewer temporary arrays, using this type of syntax, which should make it faster.

```
def conv_fft(X, R):
    fftpack.fft(X, overwrite_x=True)
    b = fftpack.fft(R)
    X *= b
    fftpack.ifft(X, overwrite_x=True)
    return X
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this and get back to the question

Comment: I didn't include the len(X check, not sure if that is required or not. You could also use fftpack's convolve directly...

Comment: I have tested it and the FFT is still slower (although a bit faster than before of course), for the record I measure the 100 executions average

Comment: Does the fftpack `convolve` function help any?

Comment: What are the lengths of the signals?

Comment: less than 50 values, and are not really signals but coefficients of a sere, but for the calculation it is the same.